# arithmetic-geometric mean

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ be defined iteratively, $x_0:=\beta >1, \ y_0:= 1$ and $x_{n+1}= \frac{x_n+y_n}{2}$, $y_{n+1} = (x_n.y_n)^{\frac{1}{2}}$; i.e. they are respectively the arithmetic and geometric mean of the previous terms. We know that their limit is called the arithmetic-geometric mean of $\beta$ and $1$ (denoted by $AGM(\beta,1)$).

Now, let's define $\xi_0:= \beta^2$, $\eta_0:= 1$ and $\zeta_0:=0$. Then let's define iteratively, $\xi_{n+1}:= \frac{\xi_n + \eta_n}{2}$, $\eta_{n+1}:= \zeta_n + ((\xi_n-\zeta_n)(\eta_n-\zeta_n))^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and finally $\zeta_{n+1}:= \zeta_n - ((\xi_n-\zeta_n)(\eta_n-\zeta_n))^{\frac{1}{2}}$. The common limit of $\xi_n$ and $\eta_n$ is called the modified arithmetic-geometric mean of $\beta^2$ and $1$ (denoted by $MAGM(\beta^2, 1)$).

My question is wheter there is an easy way to prove the equality $\xi_n = \beta^2  - \sum_{m=0}^{n-1}2^m\frac{x_m^2-y_m^2}{2}$ and if there is, how? Thanks for any help.

Note: This is from an article in Notices of the AMS, Volume 59, Number 8.